# Programm Crash case of too large MAX value

Tags: c, dev-c++

I implement [Sieve of eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and it works fine. But if I increase the MAX value to something like 50000 the Application crash with a unhandled win32 exception. I think this happened because of a stackoverflow.

Now my Question is how do I prevent this?

```
#define MAX 50000
void Sieb_des_Eratosthenes()
{
    char Zahlen[MAX + 1] = {0};
    int i, j, x;

    for(i = 2; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
       if(Zahlen[i] == 0)     
       {
           Zahlen[i] = 1;
           for(j = i * i; j <= MAX; j += i)
           {
                 Zahlen[j] = -1;
           }      
       }
    }
}
```

My idea was to allocate memory but this doesn't work

```
#define MAX 50000
int Sieb_des_Eratosthenes()
{
    int i, j, x;
    char *array;
    array = malloc((MAX + 1) * sizeof(*array));
    if (array==NULL) {
       printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
       return -1; //return with failure
    }

    for(i = 2; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
       if(array[i] == 0)     
       {
           array[i] = 1;
           for(j = i * i; j <= MAX; j += i)
           {
                 array[j] = -1;
           }      
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `but this doesn't work` - can you be more specific? Do you get a compile error? A runtime error? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Andreas I got the same error as before a unhandled win32 exception

Comment: Add `printf("%d\n", j);` inside the inner for-loop. You will see that j gets a value of `-2146737495` after some iterations which is out of bounds for the array. Also, someone advised (answer has been deleted meanwhile) to use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`, so that your array is initialized - this is a very good advice, but does not fix the array index issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all the other answers are true wrt. the actual cause (integer overflow), you simply missed some implementation details provided by the pseudo code in the wiki. The following works:

- Use `calloc` to allocate the memory. Then, all values are initialized to `0` which means `true` in the sense of the wiki pseudo code.
- In the outer loop, only loop until `sqrt(MAX)` - see the pseudo code in the wiki article.
- In the inner loop, mark all multiples of `i` with `1` (`false` in the sense of the wiki pseudo code).

```
for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(MAX); i++) {
   if(array[i] == 0) { // "true"
       for(j = i*i; j <= MAX; j += i) {
             array[j] = 1;  // "false"
       }      
   }
}
```

- Then, all elements which are still `0` are prime numbers.

In addition, it is not necessary to use (signed) `int` - all numbers are positive, so you should use `unsigned int`.

With this approach, you should be able to use the whole range of an `unsigned int` for the `MAX` value (up to `4294967295` if `unsigned int` is 32 bit)

Comment: you can't do sqrt(MAX) i don't exactly understand the wikipedia why but it's wrong

Comment: Why? I think it is correct - you are again starting with i^2 in the inner loop, so if `i` is sqrt(MAX) in the last iteration, you start with MAX in the inner loop. Your condition in the inner loop is `j <= MAX`, so you wont get any numbers larger than MAX anyway - but what you will get is an integer overflow on i*i if you use larger numbers .... Do you have a concrete example when it does not work?

Comment: http://codepad.org/G4MTqxOS try it, with sqrt(MAX) you just find all primes to 10

Comment: You can not print the resulting prime numbers like that. You need to check the array **afterwards** to get the result. See http://ideone.com/10eDP1

Comment: sorry you're right, but is not much faster because you need to go a second time to through array

Answer (score 3):

The original problem in your function failing is in this for loop.

```
for(j = i * i; j <= MAX; j += i)
```

when i gets equal or larger than 46349 the result `i * i` overflows and j gets the value of `-2146737495` and then fails at `Zahlen[j] = -1;`

Comment: Is i^2 even correct? Dont we need to start with 2*i? I saw that the wikipedia pseudo code uses i^2 for the inner loop, but would that not skip some numbers to mark?

Comment: @Andreas I didn't  take the time to analyze what the algorithm does, i only checked for possible errors.

Comment: Just had a closer look - the numbers below i^2 have already been marked before, so even though 2*i should also work, starting with i^2 saves some unnecessary iterations. Also, it is not necessary to loop until `j <= MAX`, but only until `j <= sqrt(MAX)` - with that, the overflow should also be avoided

Answer (score 1):

an int can only hold a max of -2^31 to 2^31:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

your overflowing the int